# Convert JSON datetime to

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I'm trying to convert this date-time - `/Date(1445828400000-0400)/` that I receive from API call to something more readable.

The UI of the tool which API I'm using shows **8:00 PM**. The server is in US EST timezone, I know it means to be that value in local time there. Currently Daylight Saving Time is in effect in US.

I need to convert the value I get from API to human readable date-time, in US EST (or, I guess EDS) time, to make sure the value I get from API is the same as in the UI. My PC is in UTC+2 timezone.

Searching for sample, I got following:

```
string s = @"""/Date(1445828400000-0400)/""";
DateTimeOffset dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(s);
DateTime utc = dto.UtcDateTime;
var NYTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time");
var ny_time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, NYTZ);
Console.WriteLine(ny_time);
```

That gives me `10/25/2015 11:00:00 PM` -- the date is correct, but the time is nowhere near to what I would expect it to be.

What's the correct way to convert that time format to something readable?

Comment: Fix your API because it's generating incompatible dates. JSON dates use the ISO8601 format, ie `2015-10-25T23:00:00+5:00`

Comment: What generated that Date? It looks invalid to me, not a standard Javascript date object, the `-` is wrong

Comment: But... if the json time is EST, why are you converting it to UTC and then converting it back to EST?

Comment: This format was introduced by Microsoft in the early `00`s when there was no standard for dates. Ironically, it's a UNIX timestamp encoded so that it can't be mistaken for a number. It isn't used at all anymore. Json.NET can convert with the proper configuration but this simply shouldn't be used.

Comment: Looks to me like you have the correct time. Daylight Savings is an offset from local (-01:00) and UTC from EST is an offset of (+04:00), so 08:00 - 01:00 + 04:00 = 11:00.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos third party API, can't do anything about it but complain.

Comment: @Will, this sample code I found here on SO. I guess I didn't understood it completely at first. I tried without this double conversion, still got 11 PM

Comment: @Kevin, `dto` from my sample code shows `11:00:00 PM -04:00`, which, I think, is local time and shows offset. `utc` shows as `3:00:00 AM` next day.

Comment: I used Perl to convert, and got 7:00 PM

Comment: You don't need Perl or anything. Check [Json.NET's documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) on how to handle old-style dates, or use a regex to extract the numeric parts. No point though, when you can just change a setting

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET uses the ISO8601 date format by default. To use the old Microsoft format (essentially an escaped Unix timestamp), you need to change the

```
var microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};
var date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(text, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

The various settings are described in [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm).